# How do I pull in the temperature figures from convoluted HTML code using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was able to narrow it down and filter for the title, so this is what I've tried:

```
def get_avg_high_temp(*args):

url_site = get_url(*args)
#returns URL for city argument from weatherspark.com

for url in url_site:
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    print(soup.find(title='Temp.'))
```

Running the above code for a city gives me a result such as:

```
get_avg_high_temp('Calgary Canada')

<tr style="color: #333;" title="Temp.">
<td style="text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; max-width: 25vw;">
<span style="color: #333;">Temp.</span></td>

<td style="text-decoration: underline rgba(51,51,51,.35);">-6 Â°C</td><td>-5 Â°C</td><td>-1 
Â°C</td><td>5 Â°C</td><td>10 Â°C</td><td>14 Â°C</td><td style="text-decoration: underline 
rgba(51,51,51,.35);">17 Â°C</td><td>16 Â°C</td><td>11 Â°C</td><td>6 Â°C</td><td>-2 Â°C</td><td 
style="text-decoration: underline rgba(51,51,51,.35);">-6 Â°C</td></tr>
```

I tried the above code but get the above mentioned HTML. I was thinking of leveraging the "Â°" to get the number before that...but not sure how that is done either.

Expected results is to return the celcius number figures

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stripped_strings` and `split()`:

```
[t.split()[0] for t in soup.stripped_strings][1:]
```

Or even better select more specific with [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
[t.text.split()[0] for t in soup.select('[title="Temp."] td:not(:has(span))')]
```

Both uses `split()` to split the strings in elements into number and unit by the whitespace.

---

Just in case, if you deal with tables [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) is mostly a simple way to get your data. From there you can manipulate, filter, convert and export:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://weatherspark.com/y/2349/Average-Weather-in-Calgary-Canada-Year-Round')[2]
df.replace('°F','',regex=True)
```

---

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<tr style="color: #333;" title="Temp.">
<td style="text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; max-width: 25vw;">
<span style="color: #333;">Temp.</span></td>

<td style="text-decoration: underline rgba(51,51,51,.35);">-6 Â°C</td><td>-5 Â°C</td><td>-1 
Â°C</td><td>5 Â°C</td><td>10 Â°C</td><td>14 Â°C</td><td style="text-decoration: underline 
rgba(51,51,51,.35);">17 Â°C</td><td>16 Â°C</td><td>11 Â°C</td><td>6 Â°C</td><td>-2 Â°C</td><td 
style="text-decoration: underline rgba(51,51,51,.35);">-6 Â°C</td></tr>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

[t.text.split()[0] for t in soup.select('[title="Temp."] td:not(:has(span))')]
```

##### Output

```
['-6', '-5', '-1', '5', '10', '14', '17', '16', '11', '6', '-2', '-6']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
def get_avg_high_temp(*args):
    url_site = get_url(*args)
    temps = []
    for url in url_site:
        res = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
        soup = soup.find(title='Temp.')
        soup = soup.find_all('td')
        for chunk in soup:
            if chunk.text[0].isdigit():
                temps.append(int(chunk.text[:-3]))
    print(temps)
    return temps
```

Also, you're grabbing the average temp, not the average high temp. If you want the average high temp, like your function definition says, switch from "Temp." to "High". If you want the total average instead of a list of averages, use  `return sum(temps) / len(temps)`.